# Perfomant Thread-Safe Coding

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency

How can this Java code's performance be improved?

```
public class HiScores {
  private final Map<String, AtomicInteger> hiScores = new HashMap<>();
  public long setHighest(String player, int newScore){
    AtomicInteger highest;
    synchronized(hiScores){
      highest=hiScores.get(player);
      if(highest==null){
        highest=new AtomicInteger(0);
        hiScores.put(player,highest);
      }
    }
    int score=Math.max(highest.intValue(), newScore);
    highest.set(score);
    return score;
  }
  public Map<String, AtomicInteger> getHiScores(){
    Map<String, AtomInteger> copy;
    synchronized(hiScores){
      copy=new HashMap<>(hiScores);
      hiScores.clear();
    }
    return copy;
  }
  public void resetScores(){
    synchronized(hiScores){
      hiScores.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Are the synchronized blocks still required if the HashMap was replaced by a ConurrentHashMap?

Comment: You have to use `ConcurrentHashMap` _and_ use the proper methods on it: `computeIfAbsent` instead of a separate `get` and `put`, for example.

Comment: Also, if this example is taken on face value ... updating the high-score table is unlikely to happen frequently enough for concurrency bottlenecks to be an issue.  (Premature optimization alert!)

Comment: Louis: Why do I need a ConcurrentHashMap if access to hiScores is already synchronized?  Stephen: Don't take the example at face value. The example was written to facilitate discussion.  I don't actually have a gaming applicaion.

Comment: This is extremely counter-intuitive to clear hiScores in the get method.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the synchronized blocks still required if the HashMap was replaced by a ConcurrentHashMap?

You do require them if you don't also use `computeIfAbsent` (or similar).  You need to perform this sequence atomically:

```
  highest = hiScores.get(player);
  if (highest == null) {
      highest = new AtomicInteger(0);
      hiScores.put(player, highest);
  }
```

If you simply change `hiScores` to `ConcurrentHashMap` (and remove the `synchronized` block), then there is a race condition where two threads updating the same entry and the same time will create two distinct `AtomicInteger` objects .... and first one's high score will be lost.

There is another race condition here:

```
   int score = Math.max(highest.intValue(), newScore);
   highest.set(score);
```

Taken by itself, the `setHighest` method can be implemented without using `synchronized` ... but you have to change the code significantly.

---

There are problems with the other methods too<sup>1</sup>.

```
   copy = new HashMap<>(hiScores);
   hiScores.clear();
```

If you do either of those operations without external synchronization, they won't be atomic.  They definitely won't be atomic as a sequence ... which that method requires.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a solution for `getHiScores` or `resetScores` using just a `ConcurrentHashMap` and no `synchronized`.  It may be possible using `AtomicReference` as well, but it depends on a *precise (e.g. formal / mathematical) specification* of the properties required of the methods.

<sup>1 - I was tricked by your counter-intuitive method name, and didn't look at the code of the 2nd and 3rd methods in my first attempt at answering.</sup>

---

In summary:

1. This stuff is a lot more complicated than "are synchronized blocks still required?".
2. If you are looking for a generic answer or a generic solution (i.e. `HiScores` is not your real code), you won't find one.  The correctness will depend on the *actual* requirements and the *actual* code of the implementation.

Comment: So the answer to "Do you need a synchronized block if you use a ConcurrentHashMap?" is yes.  What about "Do you need a ConcurrentHashMap if access to the map is already synchronized?".  Is the synchronized block in resetScores() still needed with a ConcurrentHashMap?  What other optimizations can be made?

Comment: Your first assertion is not necessarily correct.  It depends on things that are not stated in your original question. The answers to the three followup questions are 1) No - a HashMap will do, but you won't get good concurrency if the map is a bottleneck. 2) It depends, and you can't answer that out of context; e.g. if synchronized is required here, it is required in other places too.  3) This question is premature.  You can't optimize unless you have clearly stated concurrency / thread-safety requirements, AND a correct implementation to start from.